# How to access phpMyAdmin with Hosting Controller?

Tags: web-hosting, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update a site for a client. All the login info they have given me is for something called Hosting Controller. I've never seen it before but it seems like cPanel. I can create email accounts and databases etc.

The only thing I cannot seem to do is access phpMyAdmin (or similar).

Would anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What version of HostingController are you running? Are you on a reseller account, user account etc? After looking at their site, it doesn't look like even the latest version HC9 contains phpmyadmin by default, but you may be able to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually custom hosting applications used for shared hosting do not have phpMyAdmin functionality in terms of a front end GUI.

Instead, the hosting company will craft their own GUI hosting controller app and simply have it interface with a command line php/MySQL on their server, thereby disabling access to you directly.

You can try using phpMyAdmin's default port:

```
www.example.com:3306
```

If that does not work, and if you contacted your host on how to access phpMyAdmin and they told you that your current hosting plan does not support direct access, then there's not much you can do but use the built in database creator.

Cheers.